# Rank based on filtered Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

just trying to overcome that ranking problem and i stuck to find the solution for it.

Basically, i would like to rank on below based on Date filter on Cell C2.

But only want to start the ranking from cell A20 when it matches with the filtered Date.

Also increment identical values on "Prob" column by one

is there any way to do it please?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS with a relative reference:

```
=IF(AND($A6=$C$2,$B6<>""),COUNTIFS($A$6:$A6,$C$2,$B$6:$B6,"="&$B6)+COUNTIFS($A:$A,$C$2,$B:$B,">"&B6),"")
```

[image]